# How to get checkbox value from Datatable?

Tags: datatables

I want to get the selected checkbox value from the data table, in my table, I have two columns and the first one is for the checkbox and the second one is for display values.

Here is just returning a checkbox. How can we know that there is a click that happens?
Help me.

Here is the code

```
function BindColumSelectTable(DataExchangeList) {
debugger
$('#columnSelectTable').DataTable({      
    "data": DataExchangeList,
    "destroy": true,
    "columns": [
        {
            data: 'check', render: function (data, type, row) {
                debugger;
                return '<input type="checkbox"/>'
            }
        },
        { data:"FieldCaption" },
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {                
            orderable: false,
            className: "select-checkbox",
            targets:0
        },
        { className:"tabletdAdjust","targets":[1]}
    ],       
});}
```

I'm using jquery data table

Comment: Please create snippet with demo data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I use `onclick` function for each click it will trigger the function

```
   function BindColumSelectTable(DataExchangeList) {
    debugger
    $('#columnSelectTable').DataTable({      
        "data": DataExchangeList,
        "destroy": true,
        "columns": [
            {
                data: 'ColumnCheck', render: function (data, type, row) {
                    debugger;                    
                    return '<input type="checkbox" onclick="ColumnCheck(this)"/>'
                }
            },
            { data:"FieldCaption" },
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {                
                orderable: false,
                className: "select-checkbox",
                targets:0
            },
            { className:"tabletdAdjust","targets":[1]}
        ],       
    });
}

the above code is the same i used in the question only one thing i added is an onclick function

and the onclick function is 

    function ColumnCheck(thisObj) {
    debugger;
    var dataExchangeCheckColumnVM = $('#columnSelectTable').DataTable().row($(thisObj).parents('tr')).data();
    var dataExchangeCheckColumnList = $('#columnSelectTable').DataTable().rows().data();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataExchangeCheckColumnList.length; i++) {
        if (dataExchangeCheckColumnList[i].FieldCaption !== null) {
            if (dataExchangeCheckColumnList[i].FieldCaption === dataExchangeCheckColumnVM.FieldCaption) {
                dataExchangeCheckColumnList[i].ColumnCheck = thisObj.checked;
            }
        }
    }
    _dataExchangeColumnList = dataExchangeCheckColumnList;
}
```

so i used an property **ColumnCheck ** it is boolean variable. on each iteration it will added a true value if check box is checked

Answer (score 1):

```
function BindColumSelectTable(DataExchangeList) {
$('#columnSelectTable').DataTable({      
"data": DataExchangeList,
"destroy": true,
"columns": [
    {
        data: 'check', render: function (data, type, row) {
            var checkbox = $("<input/>",{
              "type": "checkbox"
            });
        if(data === "1"){
            checkbox.attr("checked", "checked");
            checkbox.addClass("checked");
        }else{
            checkbox.addClass("unchecked");
        }
        return checkbox.prop("outerHTML")
      }
    },
    { data:"FieldCaption" },
],
"columnDefs": [
    {                
        orderable: false,
        className: "select-checkbox",
        targets:0
    },
    { className:"tabletdAdjust","targets":[1]}
],
});}
```

Try this

Comment: This works when the value checked or not is already available. i want to pass checked value .

Comment: You can use row["column"] for passing a value to the checkbox  @dhanildinesan

Comment: thank you for your time. I got the answer just twisting the same