# How to Get cell values from data table ? Cell values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

[image: data table image capture]

I use checkbox inside data table cell and after one or more checkbox checked , i show the Add button to make changes . but my problem is i cant take values from cells after checking checkboxes . if i can take values of checked checkboxes then i can send them to data table make necessary changes

```
<td class="denetleme">
    <div class="vs-checkbox-con vs-checkbox-success">
        <input class="selectAll_1 selectinput" type="checkbox" value="true" >
        <span class="vs-checkbox">
            <span class="vs-checkbox--check">
                <i class="vs-icon feather icon-check"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

if one or more checkbox checked in a line, then take these checkboxes and columns id also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUf5D.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get checkbox value from Datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085101/how-to-get-checkbox-value-from-datatable)

Comment: Or, one of the answers in [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdatatables%5D+get+checkbox+values) may also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get entire data of cell with `.selectinput`

```
$('#mytable .selectinput').each(function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: This will work fine - until DataTables starts using paging (e.g. displaying  10 records out of 1,000). Then, it will only see checkboxes for the displayed rows.

Comment: $('#saveBtn').click(function () { ``` i need checked checkbox values with their row id when we cliked to save button ``` });

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#saveBtn').click(function () {
 
        var dataArr = [];
        $.each($("#genelTablo tr.selected td.checkElement input.selectinput"), function () { //get each tr which has selected class

            
            var getColumnOfTd = $(this).closest("td")
            
            console.log("column", table.cell(getColumnOfTd).index().column, table.cell(getColumnOfTd).index().row)
            dataArr.push({
                columnName: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first-child").text(),
                columnId: table.cell(getColumnOfTd).index().column,
                rowId: table.cell(getColumnOfTd).index().row,
                inputValue: $(this).val()
            })
 
            //dataArr.push($(this).find('td.checkElement input').val()); //find its first td and push the value
            //dataArr.push($(this).find('td:first').text()); You can use this too
        });
        console.log("here",dataArr);

 
 
    });
```